# upload the file twice in database

Tags: asp.net, sql

I using ASP.net program and SQL database

and I want to upload various files to the database

I used this code to do that, but it does upload the file twice in database

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Partial Class Document
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Function InsertUpdateData(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand) As Boolean
        'Dim strConnString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conString").ConnectionString
        Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SON\SQLDB;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=True")
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = con
        Try
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
            Return False
        Finally
            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Function

    Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
        ' Read the file and convert it to Byte Array 
        Dim filePath As String = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
        Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
        Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(filename)
        Dim contenttype As String = String.Empty

        'Set the contenttype based on File Extension
        Select Case ext
            Case ".doc"
                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word"
                Exit Select
            Case ".docx"
                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word"
                Exit Select
            Case ".xls"
                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
                Exit Select
            Case ".xlsx"
                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
                Exit Select
            Case ".jpg"
                contenttype = "image/jpg"
                Exit Select
            Case ".png"
                contenttype = "image/png"
                Exit Select
            Case ".gif"
                contenttype = "image/gif"
                Exit Select
            Case ".pdf"
                contenttype = "application/pdf"
                Exit Select
        End Select
        If contenttype <> String.Empty Then
            Dim fs As Stream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream
            Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
            Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)

            'insert the file into database 
            Dim strQuery As String = "insert into ArchivedFile" _
            & "(Name, contenttype, Data )" _
            & " values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)"
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value _
            = contenttype
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes
            InsertUpdateData(cmd)
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
            lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully"
        Else
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            lblMessage.Text = "File format not recognised." _
            & " Upload Image/Word/PDF/Excel formats"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I do not know what the exact problem is.
I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

You have the code attached to a button - any chance someone is just double-clicking on the button?

Comment: I tried several times to make sure that
I'm sure I clicked one time

Comment: Had this happen one time where two event handlers associated with same event.  i.e. copied code...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is determine what part(s) of your code are running twice.  Use debugging and breakpoints to determine how many times `Sub btnUpload_Click` runs, how many times `Function InsertUpdateData` is called, etc.

Also, from the context of your question I gather the double-insert is happening when you test it, not just in production.  Is that accurate?

If that doesn't lead you directly to the cause of the problem, please update your question with the results so we can examine further.

My suspicion is that `btnUpload_Click` fires twice for some reason, if that turns out to be the case please post the markup for your button, whether it is contained in an `UpdatePanel`, and any client script that may be applicable.

Comment: I have tried to use the breakpoints and i faced argument null exception was unhandled at  line of Sub btnUpload_Click 

I do not know where is the problem

Comment: OK that's confusing, how is the code executing if there's an unhandled exception?